# How to create a regex that checks the string contains specific pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement where I need to traverse through the string and get the first occurrence of a specific pattern like as follows,

```
i am a new **point**
```

On the occurrence of two consecutive character it must return true.

```
I must *not* be returned or*
```

The above pattern must return false.I tried to create regex following few links but the string.match method always returns null.
My code,

```js
var getFormat = function(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById('editor');
  var startIndex = element.selectionStart;
  var selectedText = element.value.slice(startIndex);
  var regex = new RegExp(/(\b(?:([*])(?!\2{2}))+\b)/)
  var stringMatch = selectedText.match(regex);
  console.log('stringMatch', stringMatch);

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <textarea onclick='getFormat(event);' rows='10' cols='10' id='editor'></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

As I am new to regex I couldn't figure out where I am wrong.Could anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1):

> On the occurrence of two consecutive character it must return true.

If I'm understanding you correctly. You just want to check if a string contains two consecutive characters, no matter which character. Then It should be enough doing:

```
(.)\1
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/8AA8ff/1)

This is of course assuming that it's literally any character. As in two consecutive whitespaces also being a valid match.

If you just need to check if there's two stars after each other. Then you don't really need regex at all.

```
s = "i am a new **point**";

if (s.indexOf("**") != -1)
    // it's a match
```

If it's because you need the *beginning* and *end* of the two stars.

```
begin = s.indexOf("**");
end = s.indexOf("**", begin + 1);
```

Which you with regex could do like this:

```
((.)\2)(.*?)\1
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/8AA8ff/2)

Comment: I have to check whether the string is bounded by ** or _ .If is bounded by these special characters alone it must return true.

Comment: Bounded? Do you mean whether there's two sets before and after something? Because if so I just added something in relation to that.